# how to set width of tittle row of a table?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

```
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(ActivityAddFlashcard.this);
        TableRow tittleRow = new TableRow(ActivityAddFlashcard.this);
        TableRow fRow = new TableRow(ActivityAddFlashcard.this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                , LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        fRow.addView(getTextView("کلمه"));
        fRow.addView(getTextView("معنی"));
        TextView tv = new TextView(ActivityAddFlashcard.this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(tl.getWidth() // <---- //return 0 
                , TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setText("dksvlfsnfmmmmnv");
        tittleRow.addView(tv);
        tittleRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tl.addView(tittleRow);

        fRow.addView(new TextView(ActivityAddFlashcard.this));
        tl.addView(fRow);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                , LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        fRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        fRow.setLayoutParams(params);
        tl.setLayoutParams(params2);
        tl.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

this is my table layout, i want to set the  width of the tittle row equal to width of table.
but getWidth return 0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view can change its width time to time during layouting process. Probably you're looking for `MATCH_PARENT` solution:

```java
tv.setLayoutParams(
    new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
);
```

You may be interested to setup `MATCH_PARENT` as `layoutParameter` for `tittleRow` as well.